# Very simple probability multiplication

Tags: probability

Given the following:

`P(A) = <at, af>
    P(B) = <bt, bf>`

where `P(X) = <distribution function of variable X>`, what is the value of P(A) * P(B)?

Just to avoid the classical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), my original issue is:

`P(A|B) = <at, af>
    P(B) = <bt, bf>
    P(A|B) * P(B) = ?`

Comment: your notation is not clear to me, what do you mean with `<at, af>`? What are those brackets? Also, welcome to MathStackExchange!

Comment: Check if [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) applies, because then $P(A|B)*P(B)=P(A)$

Comment: Thanks for you answer Mefitico. Here the point is that I just know the conditional probability P(A|B) and P(B). <xt, xf> is a couple of numbers where xt is the probability of X=true. By _tertium non datur_, xf=1-xt.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer to my specific question: since P(A|B) =  has a different meaning in the book I am reading, that is, at=P(A given B is True), af=P(A given B is False), I just have .

Thanks for the help and sorry for the mess.